# onMount called after function call from parent component

Tags: web, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have the following minimal example:

Component A:

```js
<script lang="ts">
  import {tick} from 'svelte';
  import LocationSelector from './LocationSelector.svelte';
  
  let locationSelector: LocationSelector;
  let selectedCompany: string;

  async function updateAvailableLocations(){
    await tick();
    locationSelector.setAvailableLocations(selectedCompany);
  }

  $: selectedCompany, updateAvailableLocations();
</script>

<input  type="text"  bind:value={selectedCompany} />
{#if selectedCompany}
  <LocationSelector bind:this={locationSelector}/>
{/if}
```

*LocationSelector.svelte* component:

```js
<script lang="ts">

  let availableLocations: Locations[];

  export function setAvailableLocations(type: string) {
          for (const location of availableLocations ) {
              if(company == location.company) {
                  .... (Code to set the available locations in the dropdown)
              }
             
          }
  }
    
  onMount(async () => {
    try {
      availableLocations = await api.getAllLocations();
    } catch (error) {
      consolo.log("...")
    }
  
  }
</script>
...
```

#### Problem

My problem is that when the `selectedCompany` value is going from undefined or and empty string to a value and therefore the "if" is true the *LocationSelector.svelte* component will be shown but the `onMount` function of the *LocationSelector.svelte* will be called after the `setAvailableLocations` function. Which means the `availableLocation` is empty and therefore useless.

Why is `setAvailableLocations` called after the `onMount` in this case?

Comment: The whole setup looks like a bad idea. Just export `availableLocations` or the `type` as a property and pass in the data via the template. You can also just wrap it in an `{#if}` until you have said data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote [an even more minimal example](https://svelte.dev/repl/2049952b947b4bca88f4f07dd1c90c6d?version=3.59.0) that demonstrates that the `onMount` callback gets called *before* the method. Check the box, look in the console, and see for yourself.

The reason `availableLocations` is empty in your example is because `await api.getAllLocations()` hasn't finished yet. `onMount` doesn't make any guarantee about async callbacks running to completion.

The way I'd fix this is to make `selectedCompany` a prop rather than a value that must be passed to a method, then use a reactive statement that checks when `selectedCompany` and `availableLocations` are both ready:

```js
$: if (selectedCompany && availableLocations.length) {
    setAvailableLocations(selectedCompany);
}
```